# Fetch Url data in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I have an url in silverlight

```
https://............?data=1234
```

how to fetch this url data in silverlight.

i have seen that the request.querystring of asp.net doesnt work here.

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of the `Uri` class.

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com?data=123456");
```

Then you can use the `Query` property, for example:

```
var query = uri.Query;
// query contains "?data=123456"
```

Comment: Actually sir. This Url changes when i direct through my application to silverlight application. so i cant create an object of URI as i am uncertain with the url each time. i only require a data to be used Pls help

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. What do you have? a string?

Comment: Sir the way we use Request.Querystring in Asp.net to fetch the url parameter. How to implement the same in silverlight

Comment: Have you considered the code in my answer? As long as you have the URL as a string, you can use that approach. Please have a look at the `Uri` class.